# Why does Filename collision exist in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a scenario where I have one master branch and one dev branch that is taken from the master branch. The master branch contains some old versions of some dll:s which I have updated in my dev branch. Now when I try to merge my changes back from my dev branch to the master branch I get a "Filname Collision" conflict. Of course the file name will collide, I have updated the file and want to use my newer version. But for some reason I don't have take local as a resolution to the problem. All I can do i either take server, rename server or rename local. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you replaced the DLL instead of "changing" it, so the merge recognises that it is a completely separate entry in the filesystem and complains.

It's explained more fully [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrod/archive/2006/08/25/filename-collision-conflict-that-won-t-resolve-through-the-ui-part-1-of-2.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrod/archive/2006/09/12/751073.aspx), including a resolution:

> We cannot resolve this through the GUI so we will drop to the command
>   line and resolve the conflict appropriately. Within resolve we have
>   the ability to specify a new name for the target file- you can find
>   all the options [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yw3tcdy.aspx). The option we
>   will use is `AcceptYoursRenameTheirs` and in a namespace conflict it
>   accepts the contents and name of your file (source) and renames their
>   (target) file to a new name that is specified.
>
> To accomplish this we will also need to use the `/newname` option. Here
>   is the command you should execute:
>
> ```
> tf resolve a.txt  /auto:AcceptYoursRenameTheirs  /newname:a-old.txt
> ```
>
> After this command succeeds you will get two pending changes: 1) a
>   merge, branch for the new `a.txt` into the target folder and 2) a rename
>   of `a.txt` to `a-old.txt` in `target`.  So after checking in these changes
>   the merge relationship will look like: `source/a.txt  à target/a.txt`
>   just as you wanted it.
>
> If instead, you would like the opposite to take place, meaning you
>   need `source/a.txt` to map to a new name in the target folder then the
>   command to execute would be:
>
> ```
> tf resolve a.txt  /auto:AcceptMerge /newname:a-newname.txt
> ```
>
> Consequently that would give you a merge relationship of `source/a.txt
>   -à target/a-newname.txt`
>
> With the conflict resolved the developer is now free to check in the
>   changes brought by this merge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. But it is a weird behavior. I don't care if I changed or replaced a file, for me that is a change against tfs and should be treated as such if you asking me. All I am asking is check if file exist, if they exist, check if newer, if newer take the latest or something like that.

Comment: @Tomas: Well, TFS is not asking you. :) This comes up for binary files which you tend to replace entirely rather than altering their contents. VCSs generally handle content changes very well -- that's what they're there for -- but merging file _replacements_ is more complicated. Merging is certainly more complicated than just comparing Last Modified dates.

Comment: In Team Foundation Server 2010, the filename collision conflict has been eliminated. Buck

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times this happens if you delete a binary file in source control and add it later.
so i think you are using the following workflow:

- delete current binary file in source control
- commit
- add new binary file in source control
- merge -> file collision
  because of the file delete operation tfs cannot create a relationship between the file and won't provide any solution to fix the problem.

my workflow looks like this (it's working most of the time):

- checkout current binary file in source control
- replace binaries in local filesystem
- commit the changed binary files
- merge -> should now detect the new binary version and now you should have your typical experience